# Django Template Foreign Key BooleanField: Get Unread Article

Tags: django

Thank you for taking your time.

I would like to establish a function for users to see which posts they have not read yet and which ones they have.

What I have done: I managed to show what a user has already read.

My Problem: I cannot manage to show a user what he or she has not read. Because An article which has been read by A should still remain "Unread" to B.

My model:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 content_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
 content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 post_date = models.DateField(default="2999-12-12")
```

Another

```
class readstatus(models.Model):
 reading_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 article = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My View:

```
class DailyReading(ListView):
model = Posts
template_name = 'reading.html'
context_object_name = "data" 
paginate_by = 20
```

My Template:

```
{% if "/read/" in request.path %}
    {% for info in data %}
        {% for read in info.readstatus_set.all %}
            {% if request.user == read.user %}
                <quoteblock>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ info.get_absolute_url }}">{{ info.title }}
                            <footnote></footnote>
                        </a>{{ info.post_date }}</li>

                        <footnote>{{ info.get_abstract_content }}</footnote>
                    </ul>
                </quoteblock>

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}

    {% for info in data %}
        {# NEED HELP HERE, HOW DO I SHOW A UNREAD ARTICLE WHICH HAS BEEN READ BY ANOTHER USER FOR A NEW USER #} 
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you post your `piaoyou` model?

Comment: I am sorry. I changed the model name to Posts for easier communication, but I didn't change all the references properly. I have just updated the codes. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I cannot get the "unread" feature when I tried to loop the .readstatus_set.all. Because I have data that I wrote into the database without using Django although I set the reading default for each post to False---- there is simply no record. I need to find out how to apply the default value to the existing records, but this is for another topic.